Fetch Nth Keys from a Struct in Python
Here is my json which has nested structs or list in it. I want to extract all the nth key from the JSON after parsing through all of them. I am doing this in python and able to crack it through re-cursive method but would help to solve through iterative method. Any help here in python is really appreciatable!
Here is the logic:

Traverse every key in the json. If the key is not dict or list, add them to a list called nthkeys_list
If the key is a dict, again parse through dict till you find the nth key.
If the key is a list, navigate through each json from the list till you find the nth key.

NOTE: The nthkeys_list dont want the keys which is off type dict or list but only keys off type other than dict or list.
Input JSON:

  key:{

    List2:[

      {

        keyN1:"Value1",
        keyN2:"Value2"
      }
    ],
    List3:[

      {

        keyN3:"Value3",
        keyN4:"Value4"
      },
      {

        keyN5:"Value5",
        keyN6:"Value6"
      }
    ],
    colid:"999999999999",
    md:{

      keyN6:dev",
      keyN7:false
    },
    prrrid:null,
  },
  mesd:"d5ad787e-1ee9-4785-a02f-719fe4531748",
  dacntrl:{

    addds:0,
    keyNote:{
        cn:"dev",
        ie:false
    }
  },
  ci:620126060707,
  planss:{

    planss:{

      processid:null,
      mAddOnIds:[
      ],
      planrenew:true,
    },
    uflag:false
  }
}

Expected Output
nthkeys_list = [keyN1, keyN2, keyN3, keyN4, keyN5, keyN6, colid, keyN7, keyN8, prrrid, mesd, addds, cn, ie, ci, processid, planrenew, uflag]

That's not valid JSON so you're going to struggle. Also, why would you want an iterative approach when recursion is the optimum way of handling this problem?

U can use a queue to make an iterative approarch.
This is my code:
from collections import deque

def extract_nth_keys(json_data):
    nth_keys_list = []
    queue = deque([(json_data, [])])  # (data, path)

    while queue:
        data, path = queue.popleft()
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            for key, value in data.items():
                new_path = path + [key]
                if not isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
                    nth_keys_list.append('.'.join(new_path))
                else:
                    queue.append((value, new_path))
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            for i, item in enumerate(data):
                queue.append((item, path + [f'[{i}]']))

    return nth_keys_list

# Example usage
json_data = {...}  # your input JSON data
nth_keys_list = extract_nth_keys(json_data)
print(nth_keys_list)

The function use's queue to keep track of the data and path. It iterates over the queue, and for each item does what you asked in logic.
If dict - iterates over it.
If list - iterates over each dict in it.
The nth_keys_list should contain the nth keys from the ur Json data, as expected.
